# Office is not initialized in Outlook add-in

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have an Outlook web add-in created in React JS using Yeoman Generator.

The add-in is working fine in most of the cases. But sometimes, the Office is not getting initialized properly and the add-in only display the Spinner with the message saying "please wait while the add-in is loading...". This continues for a long time and unless we click on a new email and invoke the add-in again, the add-in doesn't load.

```
Office.onReady()
  .then(function () {
      isOfficeInitialized = true;
      userEmail=Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress;
      userDisplayName=Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.displayName;
      appInsights.trackTrace({message:'Office JS loaded succesfully for ' + userDisplayName});
      render(App);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
      appInsights.trackException("Error occured while loading Office JS "+error);
  })
```

Now this issue is occurring more repeatedly and I am unable to gather any errors in the logs. Only the success message is displayed in App Insights.What can be done to avoid this or how to find out the root cause why the add-in is not loading properly in some cases ?

Comment: On which client(s) does this issue repro (OWA, win-32, mac)? Attaching a debugger and seeing if Office is initialized could help pinpoint the issue. Instructions for how to debug add-ins can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/test-debug-office-add-ins

Comment: Mostly on Windows Outlook client, 32-bit. Why does the appInsights don't catch any of these exceptions? I cannot see any error in the logs either. Only {"outerId":"0","message":"not_specified","type":"Error","id":"0"} is logged and I'm not sure if this is related to the issue.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console when loading the add-in? Errors about initializing Office can be shown in the console. For win32, you can attach a debugger to look in the console: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10

Comment: @AhmedVali Can you add appInsights outside the Office.onReady() flow (like on document ready) this will help us figure out whether this is OfficeJS issue. If the appInsight for document load does not have a corresponding OfficeJS onReady sucess appInsight, then there is something wrong with OfficeJS.

Comment: What type of account are you using? Is it an O365 / outlook.com account / or are you testing with something else?